# How to append text to text box value using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, validation

I need append - to the present text box value without replacing present text. I tried with this code.

```
if(len.length==4){
     $("-").appendTo("#date").val();
}
```

but it failed.

Comment: is it an input field with type text or some other element with text in it. There's no such thing as a text box in HTML and from your comments below it seems it's not an input field

Comment: it is an input field with type text. I need to add - after first four character.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Though you got several(but not all) correct answers, I want to show another way to do it:

```
$('#date').val(function(index, value) {
    return value + '-';
});​
```

`.val( function(index, value) )`

> function(index, value)A function returning the value to set. this is the current element. Receives the index position of the element in the set and the old value as arguments.

[source](http://api.jquery.com/val/#val2)

If you don't want to use `function` for doing it, use this:

```
var $date = $('#date');
$date.val($date.val() + '-');
```

Answer (score 5):

You've got to retrieve the current value, *and append to that*.

```
var $date = $('#date');
$date.val($date.val() + '-');
```

Answer (score 2):

try:

```
$('#date').val($('#date').val() + '-');
```

Answer (score 2):

The most elegant way I've found includes not using jQuery so much.

```
if ( len.length === 4 ) {
    var date = $( '#date' )[0] // faster to write than "document.getElementById( 'date' )"
    date.value += '-'
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Ralt/T9mUT/3/

Comment: You're not passing in a function context into `.val()`, so the `this` reference may be different than you think. It's definitely not going to be the `$('#date')` you just selected.

Comment: [THIS](http://jsfiddle.net/teneff/T9mUT/) is your code in jsFiddle and it's not working

Comment: Alright, only the `this.value` works.. somehow. @RichardNeilIlagan is right in that `this` is not correct. http://jsfiddle.net/Ralt/T9mUT/1/

Comment: Got it working not using `this`, and using plain javascript is more elegant.

Comment: That is *still* not going to work. `this` refers to a function's context, and since you're not passing a function into `.val()`, `this` will either be (1) undefined, or (2) the context of the function this code is currently running in. It's not going to be the `$('#date')` you're chaining the `.val()` method to.

Comment: @RichardNeilIlagan I don't use `this` anymore :) and yes, it was undefined. I somehow thought jQuery's magic would make it work, as it makes a lot of weird stuff work.

Comment: Yes, just discovered a few minutes after posting the comment, I deleted it, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

```
jQuery('#date').val(jQuery('#date').val() + '-');
```

Comment: Why do you query the DOM twice?

Comment: I agree this is unnecessary, but was simply attempting to show the very basic syntax.

Answer (score 0):

I was just doing this. I used .append(myValue); here I'm looping through an Ajax result set:

```
        $.each(result, function (i, obj) {
            $.each(obj, function (i, item) {
                $('#txtValueList').append(item);
            })
        })
```